# Specific SQL query to Doctrine translation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to transcript this kind of request in doctrine under symfon:

```
SELECT node.name
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND parent.name = 'ELECTRONICS'
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
    $nodesDQL = $this->createQueryBuilder('childs')
        ->select('childs')
        ->from('AppBundle:NestedCategory', 'parent')
        ->join('AppBundle:NestedCategory', 'childs')
        ->where(new BetweenExpression('childs.lft', 'parent.lft', 'parent.right'))
        ->andWhere('parent = :parent')
        ->setParameter('parent', $node);
```

I can't join like this, any idea welcomes !

I think about subrequest but how in doctrine ?

Regards.

PS: I'm frenchy with english difficulties.

Comment: I think I need to use doctrine relationship and add more information like depth or parent's id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to join parent if each child has parent id already, it can just be a criteria.

E.g.

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('children');

    $qb->select('children')
        ->from('AppBundle:NestedCategory', 'children')
        ->where($qb->expr()->between('children.lft', ':parentLft', ':parentRgt'))
        ->andWhere('children.parent = :parent')
        ->setParameter('parent', $node)
        ->setParameter('parentLft', $node->getLft()) // assuming you can get lft/rgt from parent
        ->setParameter('parentRgt', $node->getRgt())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

This would get you all the children of the parent node where child node left is between parent right/left.